# mijovideos plugin is not uploading larger files 128MB and small

Tags: html, css, joomla3.0

im using mijovideos as my joomla plugin for my videosharing component and it wont let me upload larger files(128mb) on the second option also the smaller videos like 80mb and below keep saying ERROR Processing mp4 file but the file is uploaded.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1zsf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As far as upload limits are concerned, you'll need to get into your php.ini file and edit the upload limit on that.

[Locate your PHP.ini file](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/phpini-file/)

You can do that unless you're running off of GoDaddy servers, in which case your PHP.ini is inaccessible. So you'll need to create your own and put it in your site's base directory.

When it comes to video uploading, I'm unfamiliar with mijovideos. I would recommend using [All Video Share](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/allvideoshare) to get the job done. It works well enough for my website, although you'll need to do quite a bit of tweaking to get it to fit your site's design and format. Which is true for any website / extension, I assume.